# Add a generic ActionListener to many JButtons or JComponents or JTextFields

Tags: java, swing

[ First of all i have read this answer but i understand mine is different [Add actionListener to a lot of JButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31344633/add-actionlistener-to-a-lot-of-jbutton) ]

I have a series of `JTextField` and i need to do something when their values are updated. Usually i need to do `myAction(JTextField jt)` with all of them.

Right now i use this code to do it, but i have to make an instance of this code for each one of my `JTextField` and i want to do it only once.

```
myJTextField1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //change some value here!
            myAction(myJTextField1);
        }
    });
//repeat for myJTextFields-2-to-9
```

This what i have tried but it doesn't work because `jt` is not accessible.

```
void addListener(JTextField jt){
    jt.addActionListener(new ActionListener (){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //change some value here!
            myAction(jt);
        }
    });
 }
```

I also tried something like `jt.addActionListener(new myListener implements ActionListener (jt){` but i don't really know how to something like that.

Comment: A `DocumentListener` is typically better than an `ActionListener` when it comes to a `JTextComponent`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create a generic `ActionListener` which extracts the `JTextField` on which the action occurred from the event:

```
ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        myAction((JTextField)e.getSource());
    }
}
```

or shorter as lambda

```
ActionListener listener = e -> myAction((JTextField)e.getSource());
```

and then register it on your textfields:

```
myJTextField1.addActionListener(listener);
myJTextField2.addActionListener(listener);
...
```

UPDATE:

If you want to associate each textfield with a string parameter and pass the parameter to your `myAction` method, you can transport the parameter in the name field:

```
myJTextField1.setName("param1");
```

and extract it in the action method:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JTextField tf = (JTextField)e.getSource();
        myAction(tf, tf.getName());
    }
```

of course this could also be done in `myAction`.

Comment: Just one question, if i had to pass another parameter into `myAction(JTextField jt)` which will then be updated, such us `myAction(JTextField jt, String a)` can this approach still work?

Comment: I intend to use `String a` to decide what to do inside `myAction` with a `case` operator.

Comment: @fartagaintuxedo is the string a constant or does it depend on the textfield?

Comment: it depends on the textfield

Comment: It would be easy if `JTextField` had a hidden field like `input` elements in html, or a class label or any identifier, but i have checked the documentation and it seems that even if i am getting the `JTextField` element, i am not able to identify which one i got...

Comment: @fartagaintuxedo you could use the namefield, see my edit

Comment: Thanks, thats what i needed..i also see i suck at consulting the javadoc... i looked it up here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?javax/swing/JTextField.html and i couldnt find `JTextField.setName()` i guess its some inherited function or something. Oh, yes damn it, from `class java.awt.Component`

Answer (score 2):

FYI: Even if answer of @wero is very good, you can change your method to get it worked.

```
// to be accessible form an anonymous class variable must be declared as final!
void addListener(final JTextField jt){ 
    jt.addActionListener(new ActionListener (){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //change some value here!
            myAction(jt);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What are the drawbacks to declaring the variable `JTextField jt` as `final`?

Comment: @fartagaintuxedo variable `jt` cannot be modified in the method

Comment: can't be modified in terms of `jt=...` but `jt.setText("..")` will work fine

Answer (score 1):

Make your class `implements ActionListener`

```
public class myClass extends abcd implements ActionListener {

    public void someMethod(){
        myJTextField1.addActionListener(this);
        myJTextField2.addActionListener(this);
        myJTextField3.addActionListener(this);//add more ...
    }

    @override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        JTextField target = (JTextField)event.getSource();
        myAction(target);
    }
}
```